# Do not allow relative positioned div to overlap absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

My actual issue is more complicated, but it boils down to this. How can I use CSS to disallow a relative positioned div to stack on an absolute positioned div.

Example of issue:

```
<div id="absolute"></div>
<div id="relative"></div>

div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: .5;
}

#absolute{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
#relative{
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/VeabYX)

Is this possible with css? So the relative positioned div would be pushed down or to the side until it is not longer covering the other absolute positioned div. Basically the relative div would act as if the absolute div is relative.

To add a little detail of the nature do the issue:

I have a webpage with an absolutely positioned menu on the top and left. I then have a div in which I am injecting templates (Angular). The issue is that the templates end up under the menus. I have tried to apply a margin or padding, but is is messing up my bootstrap grid. So I was hoping the menu could be treated Iike it was relative in regards to the main div, but still stay in place.

Comment: An absolutely positioned element is removed from the document flow which means that it won't have an effect on the other elements. It's not possible with pure CSS.

Comment: However, if you nest the elements, you could add `top: 100%` to the relatively positioned element - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxNjGQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `position:absolute`, you're telling the browser layout engine that this element is **removed** from the layout of the page.  You are specifying a manual position that will not impact the layout of the page in any way.  Thus, you cannot both position it manually and have things layout around it.

You must pick one of the other, either don't use `position: absolute` so that it will participate in the layout of the page or make everything absolute and manually position things not to overlap.

There are some hybrid approaches where a item can be positioned absolutely in a container and the container itself is relative (not absolute) so that the container participates in the layout of the page and things will lay out around the container (and thus around the absolute positioned element if the container is set to be the right size), but this is really just a technicality as it puts the absolute positioned item into a non-absolute positioned container so it isn't really absolute positioned on the overall page any more.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was just hoping there was something else I could do besides use a 100px margin

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem would be solved by separating the elements and applying a float property. However, per your question, when your use the relative property, it allows you to set the position relative to it's parent. If the absolute positioned element is the parent, then your code is incorrect and keeping them separated would be a matter of hard-coding them to maintain a minimum distance from one another. However, it is not the parent then the elements have no relation to each other and you must explicitly define their position in order for them to not interact with each other. But again, it sounds like a situation to apply the float property.